# Repentance on disrespecting Parents

Tags: tawba, parents

Assalamualaikum I am 15 yrs old boy and I am sad to say that I Disrespect and do not talk nicely with my mother, I feel very bad whenever I do so , But Mine and my mother relationship is in such way that I cant say sorry to her , I know Allah forgives all sins, I want to repent But I cant say sorry to her What can I do??

Answer (score -1):

Wallkumwasalam brother, Make dua for her and put her in your prayers, Before you want to say anything bad to her or get angry remember Allah swt and , may Allah forgive you and put you in the highest rank of Jannah.

Comment: Ameen , JazakAllah Brother May Allah Guide us all to right path and forgive all our sins and put us in the highest rank of Jannah